# How to find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

Tags: complex-numbers

for $z,z'\in \mathbb{C}$ fixed ($\vert z \vert\le 1$ and $\vert z' \vert \le 1$) :

$\vert z'-x(z-z')\vert^2-1 =0$ and $z'\neq z$.

I want to find the discriminant $\Delta$ to apply the classic method but it's tricky because the polynomial is in $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

Or maybe I have to use a scalar product...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The conditions on $|z|$ and $|z'|$ are useless.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\bigl|z'-x(z-z')\bigr|^2=1&\iff\bigl(z'-x(z-z')\bigr)\left(\overline{z'}-x\bigl(\overline{z}-\overline{z'}\bigr)\right)=1\\&\iff|z'|^2-x\left(z'\overline z-|z'|^2+z\overline{z'}-|z'|^2\right)+x^2|z-z'|^2=1\\&\iff x^2|z-z'|^2-2x\left(\operatorname{Re}\bigl(z'\overline z\bigr)-|z'|^2\right)+|z'|^2-1=0.\end{align}This is just a quadratic equation with real coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

**Geometrically:**

$z$ and $z'$ are two distinct points (in a unit disk at the origin) and you are looking for a point along the line through $z$ and $z'$ such that its distance to the origin is $1$. Hence you are looking for the intersection between the line $zz'$ and the unit circle.

By a similarity transform (translation by $-z'$ followed by rotation/scaling by $1/(z-z')$), you turn $z'z$ to the line segment $(0,0)\to(1,0)$ and the circle becomes centered on $-z'/(z-z')=:c_x+ic_y$, with radius $r:=1/|z-z'|^2$.

Now you solve

$$(x-c_x)^2+c_y^2=r^2.$$